# "Import from Scanner" greyed out in Preview app

Tags: macos, preview, scanning

I have a Canon Pixma MG6300 printer/scanner for which I properly installed the drivers.

I know it is supposed to show in the Preview app under `File > Import from Scanner`. This menu item, however, is greyed out.
[image: Preview Import from Scanner greyed out]

Does anyone know how I can have my scanner show up in here?

Running on OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below steps:

1. In `System Preference` > `Printers & Scanners`, press <kbd>Control</kbd> and click the printer and click `Reset Printing System`.  This will remove all your printers.
2. Go to Utilities and open `Disk Utility`.  Click Macintosh HD in the left panel and then click Repair Disc Permissions in the right panel.
3. Restart your computer.
4. Re-install your printer.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out my problem was that the scanner wasn't connected. Plugging in the USB helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Before reseting & restarting, I recommend trying just step 2:
Go to Utilities and open Disk Utility. Click Macintosh HD in the left panel and then click Repair Disc Permissions in the right panel.

If that isn't sufficient, then go through all the steps that Chunghao gave.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the printer was installed with the default AirPrint driver instead of the actual HP driver. I reset the printing system then re-installed the printer, explicitly choosing the HP driver (which it automatically downloaded and installed, causing the printer to whir and click a few times in the process).

After that, the "Import from HP Laserjet..." option started showing up in the Preview "Print" menu.