# How do I get my S1300 scanner to show up in Yosemite Preview File > "Import from scanner" option?

Tags: preview, scanning

I have a Fujitsu S1300, and a MacBook Pro 15″ with Yosemite.

My patience is running thin. I *can* scan using Fujitsu's software. But I can't using Preview.

But when I look at Preview > File > Import from Scanner, it's greyed out.

I've done all the things listed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155376/import-from-scanner-greyed-out-in-preview-app).

And... there is paper in the loader. I'm connected directly to usb (no hub).

PS: I was inspired to use preview to scan from [this article](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_scan_images_preview).

Answer (score 1):

You can only scan into Preview and other applications which use Apple's standard scanning architecture (such as Image Capture) if the scanner is provided with an ICA scan driver. Fujitsu do not supply ICA drivers for the ScanSnap scanners (at least as far as I know) and therefore the ScanSnap scanners will not work with preview or Image Capture etc. Fujitsu supply their own scanning drivers which other applications have to support directly, and some do (such as Mariner Software's Paperless).

Answer (score 0):

If you can print using the printer, please keep reading.

The application that shows up when you print can scan. You can find this option hidden in the menu bar.

(If you don't know what application, it is the one with the same name/icon as your printer)

Comment: Thx for the tip. But... no go. No devices show up in Image Capture. And ironically I was simultaneously scanning something using the scansnap sw.

Comment: @elbowlobstercowstand ok. I added another method.

Comment: "The application that shows up when you print can scan" I'm confused. ScanSnap 1300 isn't a printer. And nothing "shows" up when I plug it in. 

The s1300 is not listed in sys prefs > printers and scanners. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @elbowlobstercowstand Yep, that would be why.